# Get the innerText of a parent with a specific class in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a function in javascript that returns the Category Name when a user clicks on a li element such as Option1, Option2, Option3.

And at this point I cannot find anything that works, can someone please help me?

As additional notes: I am not able to change the actual code of the website.

Thanks,

```html
<ul>
  <li class="has-dropdown">
    <a href="">Category Name</a>
    <a class="arrow" href="#"></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Option1
      </a></li>
      <li><a href="">Option2
      </a></li>
      <li><a href="">Option3
      </a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: *"I am trying to make a function..."*  Can you show us the function that you are trying then we can debug it and help to fix your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to attach the event to all the anchor with `querySelectorAll()` and `addEventListener()`. Then get the `firstElementChild` of the `closest()` element with class `has-dropdown`.

You can try the following way:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.has-dropdown li a').forEach(function(el){
  el.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log(this.closest('.has-dropdown').firstElementChild.textContent);
  });
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="has-dropdown">
    <a href="#">Category Name</a>
    <a class="arrow" href="#"></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Option1
    </a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option2
    </a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option3
    </a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```